# How can I choose which actions I want to see in Blender?

Tags: animation, armature, append

I have two characters with different actions. One of my character can run and swim. My other character can walk and sit.
These characters are different blend.file.
When I want to append these characters In a new empty blend.file, I can see all of
The actions both characters.
So my character who can run and swim, I can choose walk and sit action too.
But I want to see those actions when I select the armature, which I made for this character. So I don't want to see walk and sit actions, because these don't belong to the character who can run and swim only.
Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think that you can see only some actions, there are no folders to sort the actions for example for the moment, and actions are not attached to an object in particular, maybe put some prefix so that they are kind of sorted out?